# How to extract some text from within HTML code?

Tags: regular-expressions

I have this string in an elisp variable

```
<br /><b>Country</b>: United States<br /><a href
```

I want to extract out the United States in to a separate variable.
How can I do that?

In ruby I do

```
str=~/<br>(.*?)</; var2=$1
```

I read already:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html

Comment: Is this a limited use case? If not, I recommend using a package or library that parses HTML instead of using regular expressions. For example, in ancient times I used the perl’s `HTML::Tree` package. I’m guessing elisp has a similar package to support browsing via eww.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same in Elisp:

```
(when (string-match "<br>\\(.*?\\)<" STR)
  (match-string 1 STR))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Emacs 25+ has been compiled with `libxml2` support, you can also parse and manipulate HTML as a DOM:

```el
(require 'dom)

(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "<br /><b>Country</b>: United States<br /><a href")
  (dom-strings (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point))))
```

This returns the following list of strings:

```el
("Country" ": United States")
```

Another useful function from `dom.el` is `dom-texts`:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "<br /><b>Country</b>: United States<br /><a href")
  (dom-texts (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point))))
```

This returns the following string:

```el
" Country : United States  "
```

For more information, see [`(elisp) Parsing HTML/XML`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parsing-HTML_002fXML.html) and [`(elisp) Document Object Model`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Document-Object-Model.html).