# How to invoke Elisp code interactively

Tags: help

[Related Question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42407/how-to-extract-some-text-from-within-html-code)

I want to interactively invoke Elisp code which extracts the words between two arbitrary symbols. So could someone kindly guide me to a modest document which explains how to invoke Elisp code in Emacs?

This is the code I want to execute on a `txt` file:

```
(when (string-match "<br>\\(.*?\\)<" STR)
(match-string 1 STR))
```

Comment: Type `M-:` then paste your code (both lines at once) into the prompt and press enter.

Comment: you could google for a tutorial to `eval-expression`. Maybe this page is ok for you: http://emacslife.com/read-lisp-tweak-emacs/beginner-1-try-emacs-lisp.html#orgheadline6

Comment: @jue Thanks, Can you tell where I can go to understand what it means? I copy and pasted the text in that question and then copied the command and using `M-:` but it said: `Symbol's value as variable is void: STR`.

Comment: @nima Well `STR` is from your own code, so you probably have an entirely different question (which you should post separately) about how to achieve your *actual* goal.  Knowing how to evaluate some elisp doesn't help you come up with the right elisp to evaluate.

Comment: From your question it is not clear what you are operating on and what do you want to do. Lets assume, you want to search the first occurance in a whole buffer. Then you can evaluate the following code as I described earlier: `(let ((STR (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
  (when (string-match "<br>\\(.*?\\)<" STR)
    (match-string 1 STR)))`

Comment: @jue@phils Thanks. I looked into the link you gave but the unclear and unexplained terminology there  was out of my reach. For example if I could know what is the difference between a key combination and a `eval` command and providing simple examples. Accidentally, I learnt my problem was my non-knowledge of `regexp` symbols. I wanted to replace an HTML tag with a corresponding TeX command as following: `<i> text </i>` to `\sl text \rm`, now by `M-x replace-regexp <i>\(.*?\)</i>` I could do it. But in my first edit of my question I asked for a way to find these instances and print them->

Comment: in an external txt file or at the end of the document which I guess could be achieved through `eval expression`. Now, even in my own solution if I could have an `if` command which would distinguish instances of `<i> text </i>.` _[there's a dot signaling the end of sentence]_ with `<i> text </i>` and in the second case add an extra `\␣` _[it's backslash and space]_ command. Not that it's a must, but I would've liked to be able to do it.

Comment: I guess it is time for you to spend some time at the `*scratch*` buffer and test some lines of lisp code. `C-j` evaluates the line before the cursor. `C-h f` gives you help on functions. `if` statement is available in elisp. You should create your own
function starting with this skeleton: `(defun foo (buffer)
  (interactive "benter name of buffer to operate on: ")
  ;; enter your search code here
  (message "hello world"))`

Comment: @jue Thanks, I looked into `*scratch*` for a while. I checked the `if` in emacs help but there was this `THEN ELSE` that I didn't know how I should distinguish the elements of `if`. So I opted to do something more modest as to define a function that will do the above procedure, so  I wrote: `(defun italic (replace-regexp  <i>\(.*?\)</i>  \sl \1 \rm\))` and then on the next line I wrote _<i> text </i>_ and I entered `C-j` but it only added another line break and and the word _italic_ before the line _<i> text </i>_ and an additional line break after the word _italic_.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH0RUrO_oww      and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwBRpS9Bs4U

Comment: `C-j` worked as expected it just defined the function, you can call it later with `M-x`. But your function is wrong, use my skeleton. if: (if (<1 2) (progn (message "THEN") (message "THEN another")) (message "ELSE") (message "ELSE another"))

Comment: @jue Thanks for the videos and the responses you gave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> could someoone kindly guide me to a modest document which explains how to give an elisp command in emacs?

Yes, https://masteringemacs.org/article/evaluating-elisp-emacs is an excellent article specifically on that subject.

For Emacs.SE purposes I'll list the options covered, but you'll want to read the full article.

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> which is bound to `eval-last-sexp`
- <kbd>C-M-x</kbd> which is bound to `eval-defun`
- <kbd>M-:</kbd> which is bound to `eval-expression`
- <kbd>C-j</kbd> in the `*scratch*` buffer
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-region`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ielm` to run the elisp REPL

and of course <kbd>M-x</kbd> itself (which is bound to `execute-extended-command`) is a way to "give an elisp command" in the sense that most commands are implemented in elisp and named.  e.g. `eval-region` in the previous list is the name of a command.

Comment: A kind reminder that if you found the response helpful and that it answered your question to please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Emacs 29 has also added `C-c C-e` for lisp buffers, which acts as `eval-region` when the region is active/highlighted, and otherwise acts as `eval-buffer`.